# TextRenderer: How to measure text as if it was on machine with different Dpi?

Tags: c#, winforms, text, dpi, measure

I have a C# WinForms application which consists of server and client side. I use `TextRenderer.MeasureText(string text, Font font)` method to measure text.

At some moment I need to measure text on server side, as if it was on client. I send Graphics.DpiX and Graphics.DpiY values from client to server. Based on that values, how can I measure text on server side?  The key point is that client and server Dpi might be different.

I guess, I can create `Graphics` object from Dpi values somehow and use `TextRenderer.MeasureText(IDeviceContext dc, string text, Font font)` overload to measure my text. But how to create `Graphics` from just DpiX and DpiY values?

Comment: Create the Graphics object with Graphics.FromImage(), using a dummy bitmap on which you called SetResolution().

Comment: @Hans, if I use this way, `MeasureString(string text, Font font)` method of `Graphics` object returns correct value then, but `TextRenderer` doesn't seem to take `Graphics.DpiX` and `Graphics.DpiY` values into account. Any idea, why could that happen? I wouldn't like to use `Graphics.MeasureString(string text, Font font)` method, as I know it might be inaccurate.

Comment: I repro.  That was quite surprising :)  I don't have a good theory for that behavior.

Comment: @Hans, How about using `Graphics.MeasureString(string text, Font font)`? Is that too bad?

Comment: Well, it does pay attention to DPI but it is very important that the other code uses Graphics.DrawString().  It rarely does, GDI+ text rendering is pretty borken.

Comment: Come to think of it, this behavior now also explains why we can't use TextRenderer in a PrintDocument.PrintPage event handler.  I learned something, thanks.  But you're pretty screwed, sorry.

Comment: Just a guess but have you tried `TextFormatFlags.PreserveGraphicsTranslateTransform`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this hack: Apply the transform to the font size you're using to measure: Drawing with a 12pt font on 120dpi will take the same number of pixels as Drawing with 12*120/96=15 on a 96 dpi.